# Configuring Spring Security 4 so that the "<sec:authorize url='...' />" tag can be used in XML

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have a working java 8 web application, which uses the Spring framework 4.2 together with Spring Security 4.0.2 to handle authentication via Jasig CAS (Central Authentication Service), using LDAP against our Active Directory server.

At the moment, I use the "Authorize" JSP tag library (http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#taglibs-authorize) like this...

```
<sec:authorize var="allowRename" access="hasRole('ROLE_TEST_RENAME')" />
<input id="allowRename" type="hidden" value="${allowRename}" />
```

This method has the downside of directly referencing an Active Directory Security Group in the view.  I would prefer not to do this.  Instead, I wish to change it so that it looks like this...

```
<sec:authorize var="allowRename" url="/rename.json" />
<input id="allowRename" type="hidden" value="${allowRename}" />
```

This way, I can configure access in one place - in the spring security configuration.

According to the documentation, to use url attribute on the authorize tag there must be an instance of WebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator in my application context.  While I am using the security namespace, it is not the base namespace in the xml configuration file - so I understand I have to manually declare an instance of the DefaultWebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator class.  The constructor for that class takes a single parameter of type AbstractSecurityInterceptor however, and I don't have a reference to any such as far as I can see.

Here is my (edited, naturally) configuration - does anyone know how to modify it so that I can declare a DefaultWebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator bean with a single constructor argument reference to a FilterSecurityInterceptor?

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd">

    <security:http entry-point-ref="casEntryPoint">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/rename.json" method="POST" 
            access="hasRole('ROLE_TEST_RENAME')" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/delete.json" method="POST" 
            access="hasRole('ROLE_TEST_DELETE')" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/restore.json" method="POST" 
            access="hasRole('ROLE_TEST_DELETE')" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" 
            access="hasRole('ROLE_TEST_USERS')" />

        <security:custom-filter ref="requestSingleLogoutFilter" before="LOGOUT_FILTER" />
        <security:custom-filter ref="singleLogoutFilter" before="CAS_FILTER" />
        <security:custom-filter ref="casFilter" position="CAS_FILTER" />

        <security:logout logout-success-url="${cas.server.rootUrl}/logout" 
            invalidate-session="true" />
    </security:http>

    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider ref="casAuthenticationProvider" />
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <bean id="contextSource" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource">
        <constructor-arg value="ldap://ldap.test.com:389/dc=test,dc=com"/>
        <property name="url" value="ldap://ldap.test.com:389/" />
        <property name="base" value="dc=test,dc=com" />
        <property name="pooled" value="true" />
        <property name="userDn" value="${ad.userDn}" />
        <property name="password" value="${ad.password}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="userSearch" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.search.FilterBasedLdapUserSearch">
        <constructor-arg name="searchBase" value="ou=User Accounts,ou=TEST" />
        <constructor-arg name="searchFilter" value="(sAMAccountName={0})" />
        <constructor-arg ref="contextSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="authoritiesPopulator" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator">
        <constructor-arg ref="contextSource" />
        <constructor-arg value="ou=Group Accounts,ou=TEST" />
        <property name="groupRoleAttribute" value="cn" />
        <property name="searchSubtree" value="true" />
        <property name="rolePrefix" value="ROLE_" />
        <property name="defaultRole" value="ROLE_USER" />
        <property name="convertToUpperCase" value="true" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="userDetailsMapper" class="com.test.security.auth.ActiveDirectoryUserDetailsMapper" />

    <bean id="ldapUserDetailsService" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.LdapUserDetailsService">
        <constructor-arg ref="userSearch" />
        <constructor-arg ref="authoritiesPopulator" />
        <property name="userDetailsMapper" ref="userDetailsMapper" />
    </bean>

    <!-- handles a Single Logout Request from the CAS Server -->
    <bean id="singleLogoutFilter" class="org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutFilter">
        <property name="casServerUrlPrefix" value="${cas.server.secureUrl}" />
    </bean>

    <!-- redirects to the CAS Server to signal Single Logout should be performed -->
    <bean id="requestSingleLogoutFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter">
        <constructor-arg value="${cas.client.contextRootUrl}/logout" />
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SecurityContextLogoutHandler" />
        </constructor-arg>
        <property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/logout/cas" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="serviceProperties" class="org.springframework.security.cas.ServiceProperties">
        <property name="service" value="${cas.client.contextRootUrl}/login/cas" />
        <property name="authenticateAllArtifacts" value="true" />
        <property name="sendRenew" value="false" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="casEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.cas.web.CasAuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <property name="loginUrl" value="${cas.server.rootUrl}/login" />
        <property name="serviceProperties" ref="serviceProperties" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="casFilter" class="org.springframework.security.cas.web.CasAuthenticationFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
        <property name="serviceProperties" ref="serviceProperties" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="casAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.cas.authentication.CasAuthenticationProvider">
        <property name="authenticationUserDetailsService">
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsByNameServiceWrapper">
                <constructor-arg ref="ldapUserDetailsService" />
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="serviceProperties" ref="serviceProperties" />
        <property name="ticketValidator">
            <bean class="org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Cas20ServiceTicketValidator">
                <constructor-arg index="0" value="${cas.server.rootUrl}" />
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="key" value="test-application" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: Why would you use XML configuration with Spring 4?

Comment: @Vaelyr This is an experiment with newer libraries (spring 3.0.2 to 4.2.0 and spring security 3.0.2 to 4.0.2).  I'll try java config later, but I want clear equivalents of XML config between the old libraries and the new.

Comment: @Jazz I'm not sure what you mean by "it is not the base namespace in the xml configuration file - so I understand I have to manually declare an instance of the DefaultWebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator class". If you declare the <http> element (which you do), then a DefaultWebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator will be created for you. Are you having a specific problem when trying to use the JSP taglib? Also what does your web.xml look like?

Comment: @RobWinch By base namespace, I meant that the beans tags xmlns attribute is set to the beans schema instead of the security schema.  When I couldn't get the authorize url tag to work, I assumed that was the reason why.  I've just managed to get the authorize url tag working - i'll post an explanation momentarily.

Comment: @RobWinch Do you plan on covering the Java Config setup in the Spring Security reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to clarify whenever I use the authorize tag as described in my initial post, it always resolved to `true`.  The problem is that in some cases, depending upon who I logged in as, it should have resolved to `false`.

I've just figured out why, and now its working as it should be.

Basically, the problem was here...

```
<sec:authorize var="allowRename" url="/rename.json" />
```

I've you take a look in the configuration above, you'll see that the "/rename.json" url has a `method="POST"` restriction on it.  To get the tag to work properly, I had to modify it so that it also specified the method...

```
<sec:authorize var="allowRename" url="/rename.json" method="POST" />
```

Thank you everyone for your help.

Comment: I got the exact same issue. but with Java Config. It always resolves to true, which is wrong. See my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37466594/spring-security-secauthorize-tag-using-java-config