# Spring Security sec:authorize tag using Java Config

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am currently developing a use case where I need to make use of the following Spring Security taglib to display (or not) a link based on user permissions.

```
<spring:url var="createUserURL" value="/security/user/create" />

<sec:authorize url="${createUserURL}">
       <a href="${createUserURL}">
             <spring:message code="button.createUser" />
       </a>
</sec:authorize>
```

While looking at the logs, I see that nothing happens when it comes to

```
<sec:authorize url="${createUserURL}">
```

I always see the button regardless of my roles. When I use hasRole, it works, so it’s certainly that I am missing something for `<sec:authorize url="..." />` to work.

While reading the following part of the Spring Security reference:

> To use this tag there must also be an instance of
>   `WebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator` in your application context. If you
>   are using the namespace, one will automatically be registered.

…the thing is that the reference does not cover Java Config. So I thought I would just have to define a `@Bean` in my SecurityConfig class, like so:

```
@Bean
public WebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator webInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator() {
   return new DefaultWebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator();
}
```

… but, it expects an instance of FilterSecurityInterceptor, which I already see in my logs. In fact, it is part of my filter chain already, so I wonder how I could put a reference of it in the `DefaultWebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator` constructor above?

Reference for Spring Security 3.2.4.RELEASE: 
http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#the-authorize-tag

Thank you

Comment: Can you show us the Security config you have done to secure your URLs

Comment: @SangramJadhav: as simply as this: `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMINISTRATOR')")` on the controller method. It works when I try accessing this method by clicking on the button/link. By working I mean that I'm getting the expected HTTP 403 error since I should not have access to that feature.

Answer (score 1):

To get an instance of `FilterSecurityInterceptor` you just have to add an argument to your `@Bean`-annotated method, and spring will do the magic (it will find the matching bean and pass it as an argument to the method):

```
@Bean
public WebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator webInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator(FilterSecurityInterceptor filterSecurityInterceptor) {
   return new DefaultWebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator(filterSecurityInterceptor);
}
```

**But** this will not solve your problem. When using java config, spring auto-creates `WebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator` bean, so there is no need to create it manually. In fact, if there were no `WebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator` beans in the context, `sec:authorize` tag would have thrown an [exception](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/3.2.4.RELEASE/taglibs/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/taglibs/authz/AbstractAuthorizeTag.java#L342).

I believe your problem is caused by an incorrect usage of `url` attribute. Its value is expected to be an internal url, like `/security/user/create`, but you are using the result of `<spring:url>` tag, which appends context path to that url (like `/context/security/user/create`).

Another possibility is that you didn't configure spring-security to actually secure that `/security/user/create` url, but I think it's not the case here.

Comment: Just tested it and it did not work even if I hardcode the URL like you suggested. What's funny is that when I actually click on that link, I got a HTTP 403 (which is right).

Comment: Then it's time for some debugging. Can you share your project or create a [mcve]?

Comment: I unfortunately can't share the project since it contains sensitive data and BI. I can provide DEBUG logs, but all I see is that the Voter always returns `1`.

Comment: Maybe you can at least show _all_ the relevant configuration (webapp + spring + spring-security), including the skeleton of the controller containing `@PreAuthorize` annotation?